# Como remover colchetes em uma regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Estou usando uma regex para remover alguns caracteres, mas como um deles é o colchetes [ ] e estou tendo problemas com a regex `replace(/[.!'@,><|://\\;&*()_+=]/g, "");`. Como seria para remove esse carácter nesta função?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apenas adicionei no inicio [ e ].

Ficou assim:

```
replace(/[\[\].!'@,><|://\\;&*()_+=]/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scape (`\`), ficaria assim:

```
/\[.!'@,><|://\\;&*()_+=\]/g
```

Exemplo: http://regexr.com/3g2hg

Answer (score 0):

> Sobre expressões regulares no geral, para usos além JavaScript

Ande sempre com o [guia de expressões regulares do Aurélio Verde](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/lista.html) (link direto para a parte de lista). Você pode por o fecha colchete como um caracter especial logo após abrir uma lista ou uma lista negada; por exemplo `[]abc]`, casa os seguintes caracteres:

- `]`
- `a`
- `b`
- `c`

O abre colchetes pode ser colocado em qualquer lugar, ele não sofrerá tratamento especial.

Falo disso do posicionamento especial porque há processadores de expressão regular que não aceitam escape dentro de listas nem de listas negadas, portanto a expressão regular `[abc\]]` não é tratada de modo equivalente à que eu escrevi anteriormente `[]abc]`.

Por mais que o foco da pergunta seja JavaScript, é sempre bom ter uma noção geral para não ser surpreendido quando for usar expressões regulares em outros locais.